# Parse string value in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, parsing, ssis, etl

I have the string value like:

```
string1:string2:string3:string4:2.90
```

I need to fetch from this string `2.90`

Could you please help me with the implementation of it?

Comment: *Assuming* it's always the last delimited item, treat it the same way you would for getting the extension of a file from it's name.

Comment: Include your attempt after researching the available T-Sql string functions and explain what is not working for you.

Comment: Presumably, the OP is looking for an SSIS expression, not T-SQL, @Stu , as they state they want to do in in SSIS.

Comment: For some reason I was blind to the *ssis* part. Maybe [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128663/ssis-how-to-parse-extensions-from-path-filename-strings) will help?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following SSIS Expression.

```
TOKEN(@[User::input], ":", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::input], ":"))
```

`TOKEN()` and `TOKENCOUNT()` SSIS functions are very handy for your scenario:

- [TOKENCOUNT (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/tokencount-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)